# Dozer 5.4 setCustomConverter does not work between fields of the same name but different types

Tags: java, dozer

I want to do custom type conversion with `Dozer` between fields with the same name but different types in source and destination objects.
I prepared code snippet that explains my intention:

```
package com;

import org.dozer.CustomConverter;
import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.DozerConverter;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DozerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

        mapper.setCustomConverters(Arrays.<CustomConverter>asList(new DozerConverter<Version, String>(Version.class, String.class)
                {
                    @Override public String convertTo(Version version, String versionOrig)
                    {
                        return version.getFullVersion();
                    }

                    @Override public Version convertFrom(String version, Version versionOrig)
                    {
                        return new Version(version);
                    }
                }));

        OldPackage oldPackage = new OldPackage();

        oldPackage.setVersion("1.1");

        NewPackage newPackage = mapper.map(oldPackage, NewPackage.class);
        System.out.println(newPackage.getVersion().getFullVersion());
    }

    public static class NewPackage
    {
        private Version version;

        public Version getVersion()
        {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(Version version)
        {
            this.version = version;
        }
    }

    public static class OldPackage
    {
        private String version;

        public String getVersion()
        {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(String version)
        {
            this.version = version;
        }
    }

    private static class Version
    {
        private final String fullVersion;

        private Version(String fullVersion)
        {
            this.fullVersion = fullVersion;
        }

        public String getFullVersion()
        {
            return fullVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

I receive this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dozer.MappingException: Illegal object type for the method 'setVersion'. 
 Expected types: 
com.DozerTest$Version
 Actual types: 
java.lang.String
```

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ik think you forgot to add your mapping to the mapper:

```
BeanMappingBuilder foo = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(OldPackage.class, NewPackage.class).fields("version", "version", FieldsMappingOptions.customConverter(ConverterImpl.class));
        }
    };
mapper.addMapping(foo);
```

I created a static inner class to represent your DozerConverter implementation to refer it in your BeanMappingBuilder:

```
static class ConverterImpl extends DozerConverter<Version, String> {

    ConverterImpl() {
        super(Version.class, String.class);
    }

    @Override public String convertTo(Version version, String versionOrig)
    {
        return version.getFullVersion();
    }

    @Override public Version convertFrom(String version, Version versionOrig)
    {
        return new Version(version);
    }
}
```

The full class:

```
import org.dozer.CustomConverter;
import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.DozerConverter;
import org.dozer.loader.api.BeanMappingBuilder;
import org.dozer.loader.api.FieldsMappingOptions;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DozerTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

    mapper.setCustomConverters(Collections.<CustomConverter>singletonList(new ConverterImpl()));

    BeanMappingBuilder foo = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(OldPackage.class, NewPackage.class).fields("version", "version", FieldsMappingOptions.customConverter(ConverterImpl.class));
        }
    };
    mapper.addMapping(foo);

    OldPackage oldPackage = new OldPackage();

    oldPackage.setVersion("1.1");

    NewPackage newPackage = mapper.map(oldPackage, NewPackage.class);
    System.out.println(newPackage.getVersion().getFullVersion());
}

static class ConverterImpl extends DozerConverter<Version, String> {

    ConverterImpl() {
        super(Version.class, String.class);
    }

    @Override public String convertTo(Version version, String versionOrig)
    {
        return version.getFullVersion();
    }

    @Override public Version convertFrom(String version, Version versionOrig)
    {
        return new Version(version);
    }
}

public static class NewPackage
{
    private Version version;

    public Version getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Version version)
    {
        this.version = version;
    }
}

public static class OldPackage
{
    private String version;

    public String getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version)
    {
        this.version = version;
    }
}

private static class Version
{
    private final String fullVersion;

    private Version(String fullVersion)
    {
        this.fullVersion = fullVersion;
    }

    public String getFullVersion()
    {
        return fullVersion;
    }
}
```

}

When executing this test class, you get the desired output:

13:56:34.994 [main] DEBUG org.dozer.MappingProcessor - MAPPED:    DozerTest$OldPackage.version --> DozerTest$NewPackage.version    VALUES: 1.1 --> be.smals.safe.centralplatform.core.utils.DozerTest$Version@1490eb5    MAPID: 
1.1